# How to handle when the device has "do not keep activities" set to ON?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Some android phone users tend to set the **"Do Not Keep Activities"** flag to true. This causes some trouble where in an activity triggers an intent and listens for a result in onActivityResult. 
A similar scenario is explained in this [particular bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/517427168282297) in Facebook.

According to the engineers at Faebook,

> This ONLY happens when developer options : "do not keep activities" is set to ON. This means, Android will immediately destroy your activity as soon as you leave it. Even though in normal situation this option should not be set, correct way to develop is with this option set to true so to simulate a POSSIBLE scenario where your activity gets destroyed.

How should this situation be handled?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking? 1: `How to simulate activities being destroyed?` or 2: `How to handle when the device has "do not keep activities" set to ON` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState():

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("bool", true);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("double", 1.9);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("int", 1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("string", str);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean flag = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("boolean");
    double count = savedInstanceState.getDouble("double");
    int size = savedInstanceState.getInt("int");
    String title = savedInstanceState.getString("string");
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, 
Consider this situation. Activity A calls an intent which invokes another activity B. B returns a result in SetResult, which the Activity A makes use of, in onActivityResult. Based on the result, the Activity A performs something else. 
So, if DoNotKeepActivities flag is set, how can we handle it? Activity A will be destroyed, right?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I may have to wait until I'm at my PC to help further.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have a clue. :(

Comment: Having had a bit of a look around if the parent activity has been killed and the child activity tries to call onActivityResult does it not recreate the parent activity? You can try this out quite easily, let me know what happens.

Comment: ```onSaveInstanceState()``` doesn't get called when the Activity is killed by the OS in my case. Any ideas why that would happen?